# Securing Samba Domain Controller

Tags: samba

I've been playing with Samba4 Domain Controller and all went good and we put in to production, As regular Vulnerability test we found that samba domain controller allows anonymous ldap binding and it lists all users and ou everything.
I was using simple "enum4linux" script and it lists all user details, can anyone give any suggestion to fix this security issue?